# How to read and write mathematics ?

Tags: support, mathjax

A very basic question:

How to type mathematics correctly in this website? I am a new member.

Thanks

Comment: Oh, I expected this question to be literally 'How to read and write mathematics?" :-(

Comment: @Robert. Me too and I had the answer: "From left to right".  :-)

Comment: @Agusti: not [necessarily true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Yoshida_Soroban.jpg).

Comment: @Willie Wong: And we should not forget all Arabic journals :)

Comment: @Willie and AD.  :-DD   @Yuan. More seriously: look at some questions an answers. Particularly, when there is a link on the right side of "edited", at the end. Click on it. Then click on "view source". This lingo is called "LaTeX".

Answer (score 2):

TO briefly expand on Agusti's answer, $\LaTeX$ is used to represent math.  You simply put the symbol $ in front of and after the math.

You can see the $\LaTeX$ crash course [here](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/docs/howtolatex.pdf).  Just use dollar signs instead of their [tex] and [\tex] symbols.  You can practice in their forums if you like.  They have a button where you can preview $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I think you meant to type `\LaTeX` ($\LaTeX$) and not `\Latex` ($\Latex$).

Comment: Yes, the camel caps matter (also with `\TeX`).

Comment: Thanks!  Those caps are Important!

Comment: how bout $\LaTeXe$?

Comment: @978: Perhaps `\LaTeX2e` ($\LaTeX2e$). *Edit:* Huh, that's not the $2_{\textstyle\varepsilon}$ logo I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Rahul: Oui, précisément.